# subtract 2 cells from each row in excel

Tags: excel

Looking for a way to subtract 2 different cells in every row. How would I make a formula.
I have tried the following

```
=G&ROW()-B&ROW()
```

Comment: Why just not use the actual row number? Excel's references adjusts automatically if you use Fill or Copy/Paste the formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=G1-B1
```

in row 1, when you drag it Excel will automatically adjust it for you.

If you don't want Excel to change the range when you adjust, you should use $

```
=$G$1-$B$1
```

If you just wanted to adjust the row but keep the column static you can use

```
=$G1-$B1
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you click the tiny black square at the right-bottom of the selected cell and drag the formula down it will copy it automatically increasing row numbers.